# Quadratic form of matrix (determine the nature of matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

A 2*2 square matrix having all elements zero(0) is? 1)Positive definite 2) negative definite 3)indefinite 4) semi definite and why?

My approach - Acc to definition if all the principle minors are >0 then it is positive definite and if the element in first row and first column is <0 and all other principle minors are >0 then it is negative definite .So it is none of the two.But then is it indefinite(?)

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the matrix is neither positive definite nor negative definite. 
The matrix is positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite at the same time. According to definitions principal minors of A are nonnegative and nonpositive. Or equivalently, $x^T A x \geq 0 (\leq 0) \forall x$.